# как работает унарный оператор +?

Tags: c++

Мне нужно знать как он работает на низком уровне когда я пишу
`a + b` что происходит?

вопрос вроде простой но и сложный одновременно.

```
int main() {
 int a, b, c;
 a = 3;
 b = 2;
 c = 0;

 c = (a + b); // мне нужно знать как он считает, что делает программа с данными 3 и 2 что бы сложить их вместе.

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: А где здесь **унарный** оператор? А что делает? Если включен оптимизатор - скорее всего вообще ничего. Если оптимизатор выключен - вероятно, загружает значение из памяти, где лежит переменная `a`, в регистр, из `b` - во второй, выполняет команду сложения, записывает полученное значение в память, где лежит переменная `c`...

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/5pk07C

Comment: Хорошо пусть будет `a` и `b` динамическими переменными.
Программа открывается спрашивает меня ввести цифру `a` и цифру `b`
по какому принципу выполняется это сложение?

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в асемблере, не могу понять что он делает, такое чувство что там сразу результат вычислений записан.

Comment: *Я не разбираюсь в асемблере* Ну как тогда объяснять? Есть проводочки, по которым идут сигналы, и если в соответствующих проводочках есть ток, то процессор вычислит сумму...  Опять - как объявнить, как он вычислит сумму? Что вы хотите услышать, на каком уровне? И вообще, какая вам разница, КАК он это делает - с точки зрения программы на С++ это неважно. Считайте, что там сидит маленький человечек и считает на бумажке... А ассемблер вы не знаете...

Comment: + - бинарный оператор

Comment: @Mikhailo мне это важно, я хочу увидеть этот алгоритм при котором он берет `a` и складывает его с `b`, если алгоритма нету то как он это делает?

Comment: Но на каком уровне? Как объяснять? Вот так - понятно? http://mtcol.ru/elt/logics/project/p21aa1.html

Comment: Или так - https://www.cyberforum.ru/algorithms/thread343448.html

Comment: На ассемблере есть команда, которая берет значение по адресу и складывает его с текущим значением регистра. Примерно так
start:
mov eax,3
add eax,2
ret
end start

Comment: @Mikhailo да это подойдет спасибо.

Comment: [сумматор из домино](https://habr.com/ru/post/221639/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложение двоичных чисел происходит так же, как десятичных. Цифры складываются, начиная с меньшего разряда. Если сумма больше 1, то происходит перенос.

> ```
>  101
>  110
> ----
> 1011
> ```

Comment: Человек же написал - *Я не разбираюсь в асемблере, не могу понять что он делает*

Comment: Я посмотрела вашу ссылку, изменила ответ. Человек не знает, как складывать числа. Вы читали "Недоросль"?

Comment: Митрофан (вычисляя, шепчет). Нуль да нуль — нуль. Один да один... (Задумался.)

Comment: Я пытаюсь понять как работает этот Сумматор но чет все супер сложно.

Comment: Вам понятен мой ответ?

Comment: С двоичными числами достаточно сложно понять, но придположим они сложились. Дальше получается программа понимает что за число под номером
`101` - 5
`110` - 6

ответ `1011` - 11

Comment: а где тогда данные хранятся что значит двоичное число 101, 110, и 1011

Comment: Еще я не понимаю он получается любое число разбирает по одному символу, тоесть 101 это 1,0,1 а 1011 это 1,0,1,1

Comment: @user362551, нигде эти данные не хранятся. `101` это не «номер» числа 5, а **само число 5**, только записанное в двоичной системе счисления (загуглите, что это).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы узнать реалезацию как считает, посмотрите ассемблерный код. Можно в интернете компиляторы попросить или самому. Слово `volatile` - запрещает оптимизировать переменые вплоть до вычёркивания данного кода.

```
// g++ -Os -S asmsum.cpp
int main() {
 volatile int a, b, c;
 a = 3;
 b = 2;
 c = 0;

 c = (a + b); // мне нужно знать как он считает, что делает программа с данными 3 и 2 что бы сложить их вместе.

 return 0;
}
```

Вот как `g++` может реализовать.

```
.file   "asmsum.cpp"
.text
.section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
.cfi_startproc
movl    $3, -12(%rsp) // заносить в стек числа : a
movl    $2, -8(%rsp) // : b
movl    $0, -4(%rsp) // : c
movl    -12(%rsp), %eax // копирует из стека в регистры
movl    -8(%rsp), %edx
addl    %edx, %eax // складывает
movl    %eax, -4(%rsp) // заносит результат в стек : c
xorl    %eax, %eax // значение регистра eax обнуляет
// main возвращает ноль : всё окей
ret
.cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
.size   main, .-main
.ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0"
.section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: `addl    %edx, %eax // складывает`
вот это надо, максимально понятно, что это.
Как я понимаю это вызывает Суматор

Comment: @user362551, эта строка вызвает **инструкцию процессора** `addl`.